# Getting error while extracting the twitter data using Apache Flume

Tags: twitter4j, cloudera-cdh, flume-ng

I am new to Hadoop. Trained and started practising it.  **I am using cloudera quickstart VM (CDH5.5) for my practise.**

Configured Apache flume twitter data extraction as specified below

## setting properties of agent

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter 
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel 
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
```

## configuring sources

```
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = <consumerKey> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = <consumerSecret> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = <accessToken> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = <accessTokenSecret>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = morning, night, hadoop, bigdata
```

## configuring channels

```
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

## configuring sinks

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/flume/tweets/ TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
```

When i run the flume to extract the data, i am getting the error as mentioned below.

**WARN twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Parameter not accepted with the role. 406:Returned by the Search API when an invalid format is specified in the request.
Returned by the Streaming API when one or more of the parameters are not suitable for the resource. The track parameter, for example, would throw this error if:
The track keyword is too long or too short.
The bounding box specified is invalid.
No predicates defined for filtered resource, for example, neither track nor follow parameter defined.
Follow userid cannot be read.
Parameter track item index 0 too short:**

Can anyone please help in resolving the error?

Answer (score 0):

The hdfs port number you are using in this line is incorrect.
hdfs://localhost:9000/user/flume/tweets/

The correct line should be:
hdfs://localhost:8020/user/flume/tweets

You can check the port number used in cloudera here:
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_ports_cdh5.html

Also, if you look the warning you are getting is because of twitter4j.jar library file.
Please ensure the jar file you are using should be correct. I would suggest you to extract the file in eclipse and re-build the jar just to ensure everything should be correct.